# need mySQL/php advice how to build specific mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, database

The following description is a simple example with questions and answers. But the logic of my site is similar.

Lets say tables are:

```
USERS table: USER_ID, etc
QUESTIONS table: QUESTION_ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, CORRECT_RESPONSE, AVAILABLE
RESPONSES table: QUESTION_ID, USER_ID, RESPONSE_VALUE
PROFILE table: USER_ID, CATEGORY_Questions, YEAR, NUMBER_OF_ANSWERED, Number_OF_CORRECT, POINTS
```

The questions will be available to be answered by users for few hours. Every question has the same 3 choices for answers YES/NO/DEPENDS.

Noone knows the answer(even admin) before some time passes. In the meantime USERS can choose their response which is stored to RESPONSES table.

After some time I will manually add to mysql table the `CORRECT_RESPONSE` and mark the question as `AVAILABLE="NO"`. So users can't answer this question anymore.

Then I want to automatically check users' RESPONSE_VALUE for each question(ID) that isn't AVAILABLE to see if they chose correct or not. And then add them points for every correct answer.

I made another table called Profile that stores Userid , category of questions, how many answered, how many were correct, timeperiod and how many points got for that category of questions. I do this in order to get statistics faster for every user on every category etc.

So after I "mark" a question as finished(`AVAILABLE="NO"`) and I have submitted the CORRECT_RESPONSE what is the best way to check for users' correct `RESPONSE_VALUEs` and then update the profile table?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the users and run these queries:

Get total questions answered

```
select responses.question_id from responses where responses.user_id=USER_ID
```

Get amount of correct answers

```
select responses.question_id from responses where responses.user_id=USER_ID and responses.question_id = questions.question_id and responses.response_value=questions.correct_response
```

**EDIT**

I'm assuming you have an admin interface of some sort.  I would just add a button "Correct Answers" that runs the code to correct all the answers.  If you dont have an admin interface the easiest way would be to put a single script in a protected folder that would run the corrections.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Maybe I wasn't clear. I don't mean a specific query but what method to use. Cronjob, Triggers etc. And how exactly to do it? (I've never used those before)

Comment: Yes I have an admin panel. So for example you suggest, when I add the CORRECT_RESPONSE and mark a Question as finished, to run this code too, right? So no need for cron jobs,triggers etc?

Comment: yes, if you can you should incorporate the code into your admin panel for whenever a question is marked as finished. if not possible a separate script would do. no cron/triggers needed.

Comment: thats the easy part...when you're looping through all the users collecting this data make sure run a query that updates that user with the info.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what Galen said you would then want to add a variable

```
 $num_correct++; while looping through the query
        update PROFILE SET Number_OF_CORRECT = $num_correct WHERE USER_ID=responses.user_id
```